# Intellij jsf file creation shortcuts

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea

I am sorry for the generic title, i recently moved to intellij from netbeans, in netbeans when i worked with jsf i and had many creation shortcuts to choose, so i could easily set up precompiled beans, jsf components or entities from data-tables. In intellij when i right click `web-> new` i have `jsf`, `jsp`, and few other file types like `javascript` or `html`. Is there a way to add more or edit them ? Just a link to a specific tutorial or documentation would be really appreciated.

Comment: You could open "View | Tool Windows | Web"  and there select "New | Servlet/Filter/Listener"

Answer (score 0):

You must [enable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-for-jsf-application-development.html#plugin)  JSF plugin:

**File -> Settings -> Plugins -> enable JSF plugin**

[more info](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javaserver-faces-jsf.html)

Comment: `Java EE: Java Server Faces` plugin is the only one i can find in the list, it's enabled